# How to programmatically create formulas in ExtJS viewmodel?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, extjs, viewmodel

In ExtJS 6.2, how can I programmatically create formulas?

In my viewmodel I added a constructor, where I'm adding formulas trying to follow what it says here https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299121-Add-Formulas-to-ViewModel-dynamically but my formulas seem to be overwriting the already existing formulas in viewmodel. Also the formulas I add don't seem to be working.

```js
   constructor: function(config) {
      this.callParent(arguments);

      const newFormula = {
            test: {
               bind : { bindTo : '{mystore}' },
               get  : mystore => mystore.findExact('type', 'something') !== -1
            }
         };

      this.setFormulas( {...this.getFormulas(), ...newFormula} );
   }
```

Using this way the new formulas work along with the already defined ones, but calling viewmodel `getFormulas()` does not list the formula that existed before, only the ones added in `config` on constructor.

```js
constructor: function(config) {
      config.formulas = config.formulas || {};

      config.formulas.test = {
            bind : { bindTo : '{mystore}' },
            get  : mystore => mystore.findExact('type', 'something') !== -1
      };

      this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the already existing formulas and merging into config make it work:

```js
constructor: function(config) {
      config.formulas = {...config.formulas, ...this.config.formulas};

      config.formulas.test = {
            bind : { bindTo : '{mystore}' },
            get  : mystore => mystore.findExact('type', 'something') !== -1
      };

      this.callParent(arguments);
}
```